# Understand bind in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to understand more about the bind method

I can't figure out, why that code doesn't work, (I reduce my problem to this, to help me understand the reason), thank you so much for your time

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Game(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = 0

        self.bind(a=self.f)

    def f(self, *args):
        print("ok")


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.game = Game()
        return self.game


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test2.py", line 23, in <module>
        TestApp().run()
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
        root = self.build()
    File "test2.py", line 18, in build
        self.game = Game()
    File "test2.py", line 10, in __init__
        self.bind(a=self.f)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 427, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
KeyError: 'a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) are reviewed:

> **bind(**kwargs)**
>   Bind an event type or a **property** to a callback

<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

As noted, it is indicated by property that is different from attributes of the class.

So using your code as a base and adding the functionality to change the value every second:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Game(GridLayout):
    a = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(a=self.f)

    def f(self, *args):
        print("ok")


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.foo, 1)
        self.game = Game()
        return self.game

    def foo(self, dt):
        self.game.a += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

---

**And why are [Properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) used?**

Because that type of properties store the associated callbacks (for example in the example the callable `f`) and then when its value changes invoke all the callbacks with which it has a binding.